# Why functions can be written as multiplication?

Tags: functions

Sometimes instead of $f(x)$ I see $fx$ to indicate application of a function on an operand, but why is it so? I know that functions can be expressed as matrices, but is it solely for that reason, or is it because functions on operands form a certain structure which matrices also have? I feel like in order to use the notation $fx$, $f$ and $x$ should be part of some structure, so that's where the doubt come from. Thanks.

Comment: No special reason, other than the author may hate parentheses.  As with all things, the context should clearly indicate what is meant.

Comment: It's just notation. $f\space x$ would also be valid.

Comment: Also have a look at [Polish notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polish_notation). Practicizing that notation parentheses are not needed.

Comment: So is there no notion of multiplication between functions and "values"?

Comment: No, it's simply notation and nothing more.  If you want to call the application of a function to a point "multiplication," you can go right ahead.

Comment: In Probability Theory, $F_x$ refers to a Distribution function not any other function. I know $f_x$ may sometimes mean $f$  evaluated at value $x$ and I am familiar with $f$ alone to mean f(x), but never came across your $f x$.

Comment: "Functions can be expressed as matrices" : This is true only when you consider linear maps $f : V \to W$ between finite-dimensional vector spaces.

Comment: @Randall Would it help to have an algebraic structure that defines application AND checks the veracity of an expression like $f(x)=y$ algebraically?